# Sort lists by date and time moved in

Tags: trello

Is it possible to sort lists to organise cards by the time and date they were moved into that list (not by due date etc. )? I have searched around and tried a few things but no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Butler for Trello](https://butlerfortrello.com) to sort a list by how long cards have been in a list.

The command is `sort list "X" by time in list`.

Butler is a bot that runs on Trello. I'm the author, and there's a public Trello [support board](https://trello.com/b/2dLsEE9t/butler-for-trello) where you can reach me if you need help getting started.

Comment: Yes, perfect. This (currently) works on a free board too using basic (Butler) automation.